# Building responsive webpages for phone, tablets, etc

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a prototype webpage for my friend and one thing that is important to him is how it looks on multiple different devices. I have used bootstrap to do vertical collapsing of some aspects of the page, but I don't know how to get other things to look right when the screen that you're viewing it on is smaller.

I have no idea how you would even start to do this...do you write an if then statement in javascript that says to load certain scaled down images with different positions, margins, padding etc when the browser reaches a set width of X amount of pixels? I'm an amateur web developer to say the least, and while I don't expect or want you guys to hold my hand or do it for me...I just want a good starting place on how to do it.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="slick/slick.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <main id="mainContent" role="main">
 <article role="article">
 <section>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="single-item-rtl" dir="rtl">
        <div><img src="img/4.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/3.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/1.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="img/2.jpeg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="logo"><img src="img/SJ_WHT.png" height="170px"    width="220x" align="center" /></div>
        <div id="text-top-carousel">
            <h1>a better way to book creative spaces</h1>
        </div>
</div>
</header>
</section>
<section class="container-fluid additional">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="icon icon1"></div>
                <h2>unique spaces <br> that inspire</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temor incididunt ut                                 labore etdolore magna aliqua</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="icon icon2"></div>
                <h2>hassle free <br> booking</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temor incididunt ut labore et                        dolore magna aliqua</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="icon icon3"></div>
                <h2>share your <br>creative space</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temor incididunt ut labore et                        dolore magna aliqua</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="motto">
    <h1>unleash your creativity</h1>
    <p>We focus on your artistic expression at Studio Junkey. We believe that your creative process is                              limited when the necessary resources are not available to execute your vision. <br></nr> We want to                          ensure that you find the studio space that has the tools you need to express yourself and your vision</p>
</div>
</section>
<section id="contactForm" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form col-md-6">
        <h3>Want to list a <br>studio space?</h3>
        <p>We are looking for more studios. <br>
           Send us your information<br> so we can connect.</p>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
                <select>
                    <option selected="selected">Type of Studio</option>
                    <option value="photography">Photography</option>
                    <option value="audio">Recording/Music/Audio</option>
                    <option value="painting">Drawing/Painting</option>
                    <option value="pottery">Pottery</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            <input type="text" name="studioname" placeholder="Studio Name">
                <div class="shortForms">
                    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value= "Submit">
                 </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="form col-md-6">
        <h3>Need to rent a studio space?</h3>
        <p>We are working very hard to bring our vision to life. Studio Junkey will be ready soon...</p>
        <hr class="style-six" />
        <p>Enter your email address and we will notify you when we are ready to launch.</p>
            <div class="shortForms">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<footer role="footer">
<h3>Questions? Feel free to<a href="#">contact us</a>.</h3>
    <div class="subFooter">
        <p class="copyright">©2015 Studio Junkey</p>
        <p class="termsPrivacy"><a href="#">Terms</a><a href="#">Privacy</a></p>
    </div>
</footer>
</article>
</main>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-item-rtl').slick({
        rtl: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        arrows: false,
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Brandon Grotesque";
src: url("fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg.otf") format("opentype");
}

html, body {
padding:0;
margin: 0;
}

body {
font-family:"Brandon Grotesque";
}

#mainContent {
background: white;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
height:600px;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
padding:0;
}

.row {
margin: 0;
}

.single-item-rtl img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-height: 600px;
}

#logo {
position:relative;
top:-595px;
left:0em;
}

#text-top-carousel h1 {
position:relative;
top:-575px;
left:0em;
color:white;
font-size:55px;
padding: 10px;
}

#info {
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin: 0px;
}

.info {
height:auto;
padding:20px 0;
background:white;
text-align: center;
color:#333333;
}

.info .icon {
width:150px;
height:135px;
padding:10px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-position:15px 0px;
background-size: 150px 150px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.info .icon1 {
background-image:url(img/icon%201.png);
}

.info .icon2 {
background-image:url(img/book122.png);
}

.info .icon3 {
background-image:url(img/icon%203.png);
}


.info h2 {
padding:20px 48px 10px 48px;
font-size: 45px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
line-height: 1em;
}

.info p {
padding:15px 50px 45px 50px;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 20px;
}

.motto {
background-image:url("img/6.jpg");
text-align: center;
color: white;
clear: both;
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
margin-bottom:0px;
height: 600px;
}

.motto h1 {
font-size: 60px;
padding-top: 90px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.motto p {
font-size: 30px;
padding: 15px 100px 90px 100px;
}

#contactForm {
background: #EDEFED;
margin-top:0px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: auto;
}

.form {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
color:#333333;
}

.form h3 {
margin: 0;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 1em;
padding: 90px 185px 5px 185px;
}

.form p {
font-size: 24px;
padding:20px 150px;
margin:0;
}

input[type="text"] {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 350px;
height:30px;
font-size: 14px;
appearance: none;
box-shadow: none;
border-radius: none;
}

input[type="submit"] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
display: block;
background: #EDEFED;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 350px;
height:30px;
font-size: 14px;
appearance: none;
box-shadow: none;
border-radius: none;

}

select {
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 355px;
height:30px;
font-size: 14px;
appearance: none;
box-shadow: none;
border-radius: none;
}

.shortForms input {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 175px;
height:30px;
font-size: 14px;
appearance: none;
box-shadow: none;
border-radius: none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
outline: none;
}

.style-six {
border: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width:150px;
height: 0;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

footer h3 {
text-align: center;
}

footer h3 a {
display:inline-block;
color:#333333;
text-decoration: none;
}

footer h3 a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color:#333333;
}


.subFooter {
padding: 0 100px;
}

.copyright {
float: left;
}

.termsPrivacy {
float: right;
}

footer a {
display:inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
color:#333333;
text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color:#333333;
} 

.additional {
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
}
```

So, like, a good example of what I'm trying to do is to make the logo and text on top of the carousel be a different size and centered and all that when the user has a smaller device or a smaller browser window...Or the three columns just under the carousel, those are set to vertically collapse at around 960px, I'd also like to bring the padding for those three things in a bit to make it look a little better. I hope this isn't too broad of a question, but thanks so much in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) for that.

> A media query applies CSS to elements when the viewport gets below (or
>   above) a certain size.

e.g placing this at the end of your CSS file

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .logoSlogan{
        font-size: 1 em;
    }
}
```

The above snippet changes the font-size of class `.logoSlogan` to 1em when the viewport is below 300px in width.

Generally you should try and use percentages, max-widths and your columns as smart as possible, before starting to use media-queries as you last resort to resize or re-position elements.

Comment: I've heard of media queries, but I can't say that I know very much about them. Thanks for the response! I will start looking into it! So its pretty much just putting the media query in your CSS with "@ media screen and (max-width: 320px)...naming the class or id and then what you want it to look like?

Comment: @newman Pay attention to the last part of my answer - It's better to get a good grip of basic CSS, before venturing into media queries - otherwise you'll likely end up media-querying a lot of stuff for no reason, making your code a mess.

Answer (score 1):

The FireFox Plug-In "Web Developer, Responsive Design View" is a big help in judging Responsive design.

And Google Chrome's Developer Tools has an Emulation mode for most of the popular mobile devices.

Put a page div around the entire page and set a max width for the page like 60em (960px) and width:100%. 
The max with is for desktops so things don't get stretched out too much.

Set the viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

A width of 320px is obsolete.  For a list of current viewports see:
http://viewportsizes.com/

For widths where applicable (e.g. columns and boxes) use min-width and a percentage width.

Design first for mobile, and test with W3C mobileOK and Google PageSpeed Insights

A score of 90% on mobileOK is very good.  Google insights 100% is easy.

When you are satisfied with the design and test results, Then use media queries using screen height and width to target a desktop.

These are some basic usable queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1024px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1023px) {}
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **Responsive Design**. Responsive design can be built right into your CSS, and it requires very little work. Basically, you create different versions of the style sheets. For example,

```
@media screen {
/* Your css */
}
@media print {
/* Your css, adjusted for the new format */
```

Mainly, you want to use `@media screen`, and a more specific selector, like `@media screen and (min-width: 340px)`. These are also compoundable, so you can end up with something like `@media screen and (min-width: 340px) and (max-width: 340px)`.

The easiest way is to use the developer tools in your browser. Firefox, as well as Chrome, have Responsive design tools built in. Select a template (like you want to design for say, an iPhone 6) and create custom CSS for that range of widths.

You can read more on this topic here, as well as interactive demos: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Additionally, another tip I'd like to give is to work in a unit called "em". "Em" is relative to the current font size or the parent element, unless you define it. This will help your rendering to be a little bit better, and more friendly to different devices.

Answer (score -2):

You should look into [using srcset](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/) to load different image sizes based on the current resolution. For your logo you could use svg images, depending on what kind of logo you're going with, or just hide it with media queries on mobile.

General lay-out issues are best solved using media queries, as answered by others.